# What does すくいとる mean?

Tags: meaning, words

From Quintessential Quintuplets (Season2,ep.3,12:00)

> これが俺のすくい取れなかった　姉妹を大切にするが故の　二乃の心理…

What does すくいとる mean in this sentence?

If I were to try to translate:

> This is what I failed to understand(?). The state of Nino's mind because of her need to look after her sisters...

I found this:

- [掬い取る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%8E%AC%E3%81%84%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8B/)

and both of the definitions kind of make sense but not really. I don't know if I found the right word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct to understand '掬い取る' as 'understand'.

It is [すくう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%99%E3%81%8F%E3%81%86/#jn-117818) + とる, and すくう is largely synonymous to [くむ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%80/#jn-63064), both meaning 'holding up liquid by an apparatus or hands' (so literally, it is close to *grasp*).

And [くみとる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%B1%B2%E3%81%BF%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8B/#jn-63039) has the more explicit meaning as follows:

> ２ 相手の心情や事情を推し量る。理解する。「先方の意図を―・る」